# The Execution of the following code fails to terminate despite giving the expected output, why?

Tags: java, execution, terminate

The execution of the following code which is used to update the redirected URLS for the URLS present in the excel, fails to terminate despite giving the expected output. The program selects the Excel file in which URLS to be checked are present then updates the URL to which the URL present in the excel redirects. Can anyone give me the reason.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Selenium_sample1 extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s, sss = null; int rownum = 6;
        JFrame Jf = new JFrame();
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop"));
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Jf);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            sss = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("Selected file: " + sss);
        } 

        FileInputStream fileI = new FileInputStream(new File(sss));

        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileI);

        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell = null;
        Row row = null;
        int lastr = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(lastr);
        List <String> RedirectedUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastr; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            cell = row.getCell(0);
            System.out.println(cell.toString());
            URL url = new URL(cell.toString());
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
            connection.connect();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            // e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println(code);
            s = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
            if (code / 100 == 3)
                RedirectedUrl.add(s);
            else 
                RedirectedUrl.add(" ");            
        }
        for (String ss: RedirectedUrl) {                
            Row roww = sheet.createRow(rownum);
            Cell celll = roww.createCell(4);
            celll.setCellValue(ss);
            rownum = rownum + 1;
        }
        fileI.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(sss));
        workbook.write(fos); 
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Task Completed");                 
    }                
}
```

Comment: please fix your code intendation, IDEs like netbeans or eclipse can do this automatically for you; and add the java tag. also, your problem description is very hard to understand.

Comment: Your code says `//For each row, iterate through all the columns` but then only reads the first cell of each row... either fix the comment or fix the code.

Comment: I meant to say that despite my code giving the desired output, when I execute it on eclipse, its console shows that the code is still executing by displaying the "stop" button even after the last statement  System.out.println("Task Completed"); mentioned in the code getting executed. I want to know the reason.

Comment: Call the JFrame setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) method when you create or extend the JFrame.

Comment: Shouldn't you something like workbook.close() at the end ?

Comment: Actually the problem in my code is with JFileChooser, when I select the file ,the file chooser dialog closes but the JFrame thread remains active. JFrame setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) will work If I close the dialog not when I choose a file. Hence other than system.exit(0) as a last statement in my code, is there any other way by which I can  end the JFrame thread gracefully?